react-draggable findDOMnode deprrecated - ref already in use
I have a functional component that has objects which can be dragged around a set area.
Those objects are then saved and upon next launch I position the objects at the same places they were the last time independant of the browser size.
For this resizing and placement part I basically get the width/height of the elements on their initiation in the dom to accurately place the objects at the same places.
list.map((item) => (
  <Draggable
    key={item.ID}
    grid={[1, 1]}
    bounds="parent"
    id={item.ID}
    position={{ x: item.positionX, y: item.positionY }}
    onDrag={(e, ui) => {
      const newX = item.positionX + ui.deltaX;
      const newY = item.positionY + ui.deltaY;
      updatePosition(item.ID, newX, newY);
    }}
   >
   <div 
     style={{ "position": "absolute", "display": "flex" }}
     ref={element => { handleInitObjDOM(element, item.ID) }}
   > 
     // here I get the elements' width/height 
     <div style={getObjectStyle(item.ID)}>
       {some_object}
     </div>
   </div>
  </Draggable>
)

So, with this setup I get a warning in StrictMode
"Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference."
There is a solution (findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of DraggableCore which is inside StrictMode) but it implies that I can use the same ref in <Draggable>  and in child <div> that is basically being dragged.
but my child <div> has a callback for the ref.
Is there a way to solve the "warning" and "migrate" to using refs with the setup above?

As you've already said, the solution is to use the same ref both in <Draggable> and in child <div>. In your case, it can be something like that:
function MyComponent() {
    const nodeRef = React.useRef(null);

    return (
        <Draggable nodeRef={nodeRef}>
            <div 
               ref={(element) => {
                 nodeRef.current = element;
                 handleInitObjDOM(element, item.ID);
               }}>
               Example Target
            </div>
        </Draggable>
    );
}

